# play multiple Videos Simultaneously Smoothly Like Fitstar

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to play multiple videos Simultaneously like fitStar App (using Scrollview or CollectionView with paging), But While scrolling its not Smooth, And giving memory warning After some time... please Suggest

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you please share your code what you have implemented?

Answer (score 1):

**AVPlayer** able to play multiple video in app very smoothly but you need to manage cell for collection view. One more  suggestion is managing **pool for AVPlayer** objects instead of creating single object.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use AVPlayer Simply with this code, it'll work with fine**

```
//Change the return value how many video screen you want
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    myCell *cell = [myTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //You can set multiple video path using array

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“myVideo” ofType:@"MOV"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    cell.videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]init];
    cell.avLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"url %@",url);

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

            // create a player view controller
            AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
            controller.player = cell.videoPlayer;
            [cell.videoPlayer play];

            // show the view controller
            [self addChildViewController:controller];
            [cell.myView addSubview:controller.view];
            controller.view.frame = cell.myView.frame;

        });
    });

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the post But problem is there, because number of times  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` called, The object will be created again and again . Thus it's going to hang the cell and start playing same movie before reaching to end point.